# Merge sort recursions

Tags: merge, mergesort

I have a problem. I started to learn how merge sort works, and now I'm stuck.
I don't understand second recursion in merge function.

```
int merge_sort(int input[], int p, int r)
{
      if ( p >= r ) return 0; 

        int mid = floor((p + r) / 2);
        merge_sort(input, p, mid);
        **merge_sort(input, mid + 1, r);** 
        merge(input, p, r);
}
```

When first recursion is finished, I end up with something like this:
Original array: 3 4 5 6 7 8

3 4 5 | 6 7 8

3 4 | 5

3 | 4

3

And then second recursion starts.
So, my question is: does second recursion starts from array with only one element ( array with only one number, 3 in this case) or from original array ( 6 element array from beginning)?
I hope you will understand what I mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't tell from your code because you are always passing the input array. But yes the idea is to divide and conquer so the first call should be with

merge_sort: 3 4 5 6 7 8

first recursion: 3 4 5

second recursion: 6 7 8

Take a look at this wikipedia picture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg

Comment: Thanks for responde, so, according to that picture, it means that recursion that divides left side is called once, and then recursion that divides right side is called once and so on... If I got that straight.